# PAYPAL BUTTON NOT WORKING for async await

Tags: javascript, mongodb, paypal, e-commerce, mern

```
import { PayPalButton } from 'react-paypal-button-v2'  

<PayPalButton                      

    amount={total}                       

    onSuccess={tranSuccess}                  

/>
```

```
const tranSuccess = async(payment) => {
        const {paymentID, address} = payment;

        await axios.post('/api/payment', {cart, paymentID, address}, {
            headers: {Authorization: token}
        })

        setCart([])
        addToCart([])
        alert("You have successfully placed an order.")
    }
```

I am using paypal-button in my mern-stack ecommerce project
but `onSuccess` it is not going to `tranSuccess` function beacuse it is `async` and `await` without async-await it is going inside the `tranSuccess` function but then `axios.post` request is not working. can anyone please help me with this. every help is appriciated.

I was expecting it to go inside the axios.post request which is not happening.
should I use any other thing rather than just using that paypal-button.

Answer (score 0):

> from 'react-paypal-button-v2'

This is not an official package, consider changing to [react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) which is newer and supported by PayPal.  You can find working examples [in the storybook](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default).

---

Since it appears you are communicating with a server you should create two routes on the server/backend to create and capture orders, and call them from the JS createOrder and onApprove functions. A full stack node example of such is in the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/